# How do I slash command spawn Mobs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I spawn mobs via a command in Minecraft 1.5? I keep doing the command "/spawn 99 1" (Iron Golem) but I just get a message that says that it isn't a valid command. How do I do it?

Comment: Where did you learn of this command? I know this is a command in the mod Single Player Commands.

Comment: Do you have the mod for the command installed?

Comment: You can't spawn some mobs like iron golemns and snow golems, but you can make them.

Answer (score 5):

That's because it *isn't* a command. In vanilla, or unmodded, Minecraft, there is not a way to spawn monsters or animals with commands. If you wish to spawn mobs, there are 2 options:

First:   Use unofficial mods to spawn mobs.
Second:  Use mob eggs to spawn mobs.

1. You can install the singleplayer mod [SinglePlayerCommands](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/94310-152-single-player-commands-v48-official-download-spc-noclip/) then type:

[/spawn  [Number of Mobs]](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4R8z-NFUCkM)

You can also use the common server mod "[Bukkit](http://bukkit.org/)" for spawning mobs via commands on multiplayer. Add the plugin [Essentials](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/essentials/) to your bukkit server (or any other plugin that allows spawning of mobs via commands), and type

/spawnmob

2. In creative mode, click on the compass tab in your inventory, and scroll towards the bottom. You should see some "Spawn Eggs" with which you can use to spawn monsters; just right click a block while holding a spawn egg.

If you are in singleplayer mode but not in creative, click
Esc, Open to LAN server, Enable Cheats, then Create Server.

Type /gamemode 1          and you should be in creative mode.

Answer (score 2):

If you have cheats enabled (if this is singleplayer), or if you are oped in multiplayer (vanilla multiplayer, you might have a slightly different command if you have Bukkit plugins installed), you can use `/give @p 383 99` to get Iron Golem spawn eggs you can use. Hope this helps!

Comment: Does @p work outside of command blocks?

Comment: Yeah, you can use the all of the scripting features of 1.4 both in the command window and using command blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Not totally sure whether this post is active at all, but with Minecraft 1.7+, you can use the **[/summon](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#summon)** command to spawn in any entity you wish. The link leads to the Minecraft Wiki page for commands.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a vanilla command for spawning mobs.

You can do the following;

- Install this [mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/94310-15-single-player-commands-v46-official-download-spc-noclip/). This will give you the /spawn command and much more
- (Unsure about this one) Open the game as LAN game, and be sure you're in creative. Then you'll be able to use most of the commands implented in the vanilla version of minecraft.

I hope this will answer your question!
Have fun killing those creepers!

Answer (score 0):

Try /mob (nameofmob) (numberofmobs) if you have WorldGuard or SinglePlayerCommands.

Answer (score 0):

Originally posted by codeulike in comments:

> Since 1.7 the `/summon` command has been added, it will spawn mobs one at a time with options like names and armour, and can be fired by a control block. See https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands